# My registration formsaves to database and says confirmation email has been sent but my mail server reflects that no email is sent out

Tags: php, email, registration

Here's the tutorial I'm following...

http://youhack.me/2010/04/01/building-a-registration-system-with-email-verification-in-php/

And here are my files.

signup.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sign Up</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="350" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="signup_ac.php">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Sign up</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="76">Name</td>
<td width="3">:</td>
<td width="305"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>E-mail</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Country</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="country" type="text" id="country" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> &nbsp;
<input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

signup_ac.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?php

include('Connections/ActivateEmail.php');

// table name
$tbl_name=`temp_members_db`;

// Random confirmation code
$confirm_code=md5(uniqid(rand()));

// values sent from form
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$country=$_POST['country'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

// Insert data into database
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(confirm_code, name, email, password, country)VALUES('$confirm_code', '$name', '$email', '$password', '$country')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if suceesfully inserted data into database, send confirmation link to email
if($result){

// ---------------- SEND MAIL FORM ----------------


// send e-mail to ...
$to=$email;

// Your subject
$subject="Your confirmation link here";

// From
$header="from: your name <your email>";

// Your message
$message="Your Comfirmation link \r\n";
$message.="Click on this link to activate your account \r\n";
$message.="http://www.yourweb.com/confirmation.php?passkey=$confirm_code";


// send email
$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

}


// if not found
else {
echo "Not found your email in our database";
}


// if your email succesfully sent
if($sentmail){
echo "Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.";
}
else {
echo "Cannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address";
}

?>
<title>Sign up ac</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Confirmation.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Confirmation</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

include('Connections/ActivateEmail.php');

// Passkey that got from link
$passkey=$_GET['passkey'];

$tbl_name1="temp_members_db";

// Retrieve data from table where row that match this passkey
$sql1="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name1 WHERE confirm_code ='$passkey'";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);

// If successfully queried
if($result1){

// Count how many row has this passkey
$count=mysql_num_rows($result1);

// if found this passkey in our database, retrieve data from table "temp_members_db"
if($count==1){

$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
$name=$rows['name'];
$email=$rows['email'];
$password=$rows['password'];
$country=$rows['country'];

$tbl_name2="registered_members";

// Insert data that retrieves from "temp_members_db" into table "registered_members"
$sql2="INSERT INTO $tbl_name2(name, email, password, country)VALUES('$name', '$email', '$password', '$country')";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
}

// if not found passkey, display message "Wrong Confirmation code"
else {
echo "Wrong Confirmation code";
}

// if successfully moved data from table"temp_members_db" to table "registered_members" displays message "Your account has been activated" and don't forget to delete confirmation code from table "temp_members_db"
if($result2){

echo "Your account has been activated";

// Delete information of this user from table "temp_members_db" that has this passkey
$sql3="DELETE FROM $tbl_name1 WHERE confirm_code = '$passkey'";
$result3=mysql_query($sql3);

}

}
?>
</body>
</html>

ActivateEmail.php
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_ActivateEmail = "localhost";
$database_ActivateEmail = "test";
$username_ActivateEmail = "root";
$password_ActivateEmail = "kathy";
$ActivateEmail = mysql_pconnect($hostname_ActivateEmail, $username_ActivateEmail,     $password_ActivateEmail) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

So when I check my databases, the info is reflected, but no confirmation email is ever sent to the email address...even though I get the screen that says to check my email for the confirmation link.

Help!
Please and Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your `php.ini` file is [configured correctly to send email](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php), otherwise everything will work but no actual email will be transmitted.

It is ironic that the website is called `youhack.me` because the code they are suggesting has some basic security flaws.

Instead of using the `mysql_*` functions (which are being removed from PHP), use the [improved `mysqli_*` set of functions](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php).

Comment: Where would I find my php.ini file?